# WinApi+LinuxApi in one mono project

Tags: c#, linux, winapi, mono, cross-platform

Is there any way to use both of WinApi and Linux libs in one project(each in its OS)? so I wont to have one mono assembly, that will use WinApi in Windows and glibc and other lib's functions in linux. Thanks in advance.

ps. I work with C#

Comment: A whole load of #ifs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an interface (or abstract class) that defines all the platform specific functionality I need. Then code two implementations and at program initialization instantiate the appropriate one based on `Environment.OSVersion.Platform`.